# Use Color in TailWind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

How to use Color in TailWind CSS ?

I am learning TailWind CSS.I am using TailWind CSS in Laravel.

My `tailwind.config.js` is like below

```
const { colors } = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      cadetblue:'#5f9ea0',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I declared CSS inside `<head></head>` is like below.

```
<style>
 .hello { background-color: theme('colors.cadetblue'); }
</style>
```

I am using `.hello` class in HTML like below.

```
<div class="hello">Hello</div>
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you need to define `colors` object array in your custom `theme` file, because your tailwind config will overide the default. So please check your `colors` import is same with official doc,

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')
```

#### Solution 1

Define your custom color name into `theme.colors`

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  ...
  theme: {
  ...
    colors: {
      cadetblue: "#5f9ea0",
    },
  ...
```

#### Solution 2

In other way, you can simplly adjust it with define in your main css file like this, [Official Doc Link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-new-utilities)

```
// in your css file

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

...
# You can add your custom class name into `utilities`
@layer utilities { 
  .bg-cadetblue {
    background-color: #5f9ea0;
  }
}
```

and use it

```
<div class="bg-cadetblue">Hello</div>
```

> ps, restart your app with `npm run start` or `yarn start` required!

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks @JsWizard for your reply. `// in your css file
.bg-cadetblue {
  background-color: #5f9ea0
}
`
Is it TailWind CSS ? I am learning TailWind CSS. Thanks.

Comment: welcome abu, Tailwind also using similar way to use CSS, all of Tailwind classes also premade with the CSS.

Comment: Thanks @JsWizard. I am learning TailWind CSS. How can I implement your solution ? Could you please describe more ?

Comment: check again my modified answer, good luck!! :)

Comment: Thanks @JsWizard. But your solution is not working. My `tailwind.config.js` file is like this `const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    colors: {
      cadetblue:'#5f9ea0',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
`. Thanks.

Comment: check your `purge` define, this is recommended set, `purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],` :)

Comment: Thanks @JsWizard. Your solution is working. I didn' t run the command `npm run dev`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In tailwind-3 you could pass the exact color inline if you use [ ]:

```
<div class="bg-[#5f9ea0]">Hello</div>
```